# Select rows of two different values in same column based on values updated in rows of different column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to update the 'Role1' from the below table for  ID in (1,2,3,5,6) with role1= 133 (Passed as Parameter).

Logic should update Role1 only for ID (1,2) as the Role2 value for ID 4 is equal for Role2 value of ID 1,2 --('AB')

So ID (3,5,6) should not be updated and printed as exception , while ID(1,2) should be updated.

Any help and advice is appreciated

Thanks

```
    +----------+-------+--------+--------+
    | ID       | role1 |role2   |Not     |
    +----------+-------+--------+--------+
    | 1        | 123   | AB     | 0      |
    | 2        | 456   | AB     | 1      |
    | 3        | 789   | EF     | 0      |
    | 4        | 133   | AB     | 0      |
    | 5        | 453   | EF     | 1      |
    | 6        | 764   | DF     | 0      |
    +----------+-------+--------+--------+
    output
    
    +----------+------+------+------+
    | ID       | role1|role2 |not   |
    +----------+------+------+------+
    | 1        | 133  | AB   |0     |
    | 2        | 133  | AB   |1     |
    +----------+------+------+------+
    SELECT '789', '453', '764' + 'As they could not be updated due to seperate role2'
```

Comment: Your question describers an "update".  However, your results and sample query are `select`.  Can you clarify?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: The output is after the update of the rows ; & rows which are excluded are shown as separate statement

Comment: How are you determining which `ID`s need to have their `role1` updated? I assume from your question that it is not based on the `ID`, but is it based on `role2 = 'AB'`?

Comment: I am passing ID (1,2,3,5,6) and  role1=133 as Parameter to the SP, and depending on the value of Role2, the logic of update works

Comment: I'm sorry, but I just don't understand the relationship that is being used to exclude 3, 5, and 6 from being updated. Do rows qualify for update because they have a `role2` value that is equal to that of a row with a `role1` matching the parameter?

Comment: Yes that is true to logic

Answer (score 0):

Making a pitch based on my understanding of the scenario. It seems that what is wanted is to first find the `Role2` of the row that has a `Role1` of the passed parameter, then update all rows that share that `Role2` and a `Role1` that doesn't match the parameter.

```
/* Set up the test scenario */
DECLARE @role1 INT = 133;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #roles
    CREATE TABLE #roles
        (
            ID INT,
            Role1 INT,
            Role2 VARCHAR(2),
            [NOT] INT
        );

    INSERT INTO #roles (ID, Role1, Role2, [Not])
    VALUES
     (1, 123, 'AB', 0),
     (2, 456, 'AB', 1),
     (3, 789, 'EF', 0),
     (4, 133, 'AB', 0),
     (5, 453, 'EF', 1),
     (6, 764, 'DF', 0);
 
/* Selecting in order to validate the output set */
    SELECT r2.*
      FROM #roles AS r1
      JOIN #roles AS r2
        ON r1.Role2 = r2.Role2
     WHERE r1.Role1 = @role1
            AND r2.Role1 <> @role1;
```

With the set validated, here's what the `UPDATE` might look like

```
UPDATE r2
   SET r2.Role1 = @role1
  FROM #roles AS r1
  JOIN #roles AS r2
    ON r1.Role2 = r2.Role2
 WHERE r1.Role1 = @role1
        AND r2.Role1 <> @role1;

SELECT *
  FROM #roles;

+----+-------+-------+-----+
| ID | Role1 | Role2 | NOT |
+----+-------+-------+-----+
|  1 |  133  |  AB   |  0  |
|  2 |  133  |  AB   |  1  |
|  3 |  789  |  EF   |  0  |
|  4 |  133  |  AB   |  0  |
|  5 |  453  |  EF   |  1  |
|  6 |  764  |  DF   |  0  |
+----+-------+-------+-----+
```